# Queries in Linq

Tags: sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create this crazy query and write it in LINQ syntax

```
select ContaId 
  from Contact 
  where 
    ContaMail = "test@test.com" 
    and
    ContaId in (
      select ContaId 
      from Participant
      where 
        ParticipantId = "test")
```

I am new to ASP MVC, so please help.

Thanks.

Comment: This can be handy starting with linq: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: What does your table structure look like? And are you using Linq to SQL or Entity Framework?

Comment: I am using Entity Framework and working with repositories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly i would get the 'IN' part of the query data...

```
        var participants = from p in participantsDataSource 
where p.ParticipantId == "test"
    select p.ContaId;
```

then i would do the main query, using the participants set for the 'IN' criteria....

```
var contacts = from c in contactsDataSource where c.ContaMail == "test@test.com"
&& participants.Contains(c.ContaId) 
select c.ContaId;
```

...and as galacticCowboy points out, you could do it all in one query with a join, like this...

```
var contacts = from c in contactsDataSource
        join p in participantsDataSource
        on c.ContaId equals p.ContaId
        where c.ContaMail == "test@test.com"
        && p.participantId == "test"
        select c.ContaId;
```

Comment: For that matter, the SQL could be accomplished with a join instead of a correlated subselect; this would then feed naturally into a LINQ join.